# Selecting group using Unknown column value

Tags: sql, database, t-sql

I have a large table with records like (id,name,Class)

**I want to be able to do a operation "Class" wise ..**

but i dont know what are all possible values  for Class

Currently i have to do is use 2 queries :

Query 1: result = select distinct class from myTable;

Query 2 : for each value from result ,
   classWiseRows = select * from myTable where Class=value;

then i'm doing

for each value in Q1.result
{
  classRows=Q2 where Class=value;
doOperation(classRows);
}

I want to be able to combine these two queries in one ..to avoid 2 trips to DB.

im using ADO.net,.net 2.0 .

Comment: currently doing trips to Db for each distinct Class.

Answer (score 1):

Get the entire result set from your first query into a datatable

```
select distinct class from myTable;
```

And then u can filter your record by using the  [Select Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.select(VS.71).aspx) of the datatable.

Also you can accomplish your task by using [DataView RowFilter](http://www.csharp-examples.net/dataview-rowfilter/)

If you would have used a higher version say 3.5+, I would have recommended [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746.aspx)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You could just do an Order By `Class` and then just partition the list as you traverse it.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps something like

```
select * from myTable where class in (select distinct class from myTable)
```

Comment: That where clause will always be true. You are constructing a list based on the values that appear in class and then restricting you results to have a class value in the list.

Comment: shouldnt this be same as group by Class.
but in .net code i will be getting all rows from table instead of
Classwise group at a time.im currently doing one trip to DB per distinct 'Class'.